# ElasticSearch Nested Query not returning data

Tags: java, elasticsearch, nested

I have an index in ElasticSearch (customers) that has the following partial mapping:

```
      "addresses": {
          "type": "nested",
          "properties": {
              "address": {
                  "type": "keyword"
              },
              "phone": {
                  "type": "keyword"
              }
          }
      },
```

I am trying to search for a specific address (let's call it "foo street"). I am using ElasticSearch 6.3. and the RestHighLevelClient(6.3).

In my case, the following variables have the following values:

```
docName = "addresses"
name = "address"
value = "foo street"
```

I know that at least one of the documents in my customer index has an address of "foo street"

My code to create the NestedQueryBuilder is this:

```
QueryBuilder innerQuery = QueryBuilders.matchQuery(name, value);
NestedQueryBuilder nestedQueryBuilder = QueryBuilders.nestedQuery(
    docName, innerQuery, ScoreNode.None);

SearchRequest request = new SearcRequest("customers");
SearchSourceBuilder searchSourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();
searchSourceBuilder.query(nestedQueryBuilder);
searchSourceBuilder.from(from);
searchSourceBuilder.size(size);
request.source(searchSourceBuilder);
```

If I log my NestedQueryBuilder object (calling toString(), this is what I get:

```
{
"nested" : {
  "query" : {
    "match" : {
      "ip_address" : {
        "query" : "10.214.159.193",
        "operator" : "OR",
        "prefix_length" : 0,
        "max_expansions" : 50,
        "fuzzy_transpositions" : true,
        "lenient" : false,
        "zero_terms_query" : "NONE",
        "auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query" : true,
        "boost" : 1.0
      }
    }
  },
  "path" : "links",
  "ignore_unmapped" : false,
  "score_mode" : "none",
  "boost" : 1.0
}
}
```

Why am I not getting any hits?

The following is the value in SearchResponse:

```
Status: OK
Took: 0s
terminatedEarly: null
timedOut: false
total hits: 0
maxScore: NaN
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use fully qualified name for nested fields. Use `links.ip_address` instead of `ip_address`.

You query should be as below:

```
{
  "nested": {
    "query": {
      "match": {
        "links.ip_address": {          <--------------------- change here
          "query": "10.214.159.193",
          "operator": "OR",
          "prefix_length": 0,
          "max_expansions": 50,
          "fuzzy_transpositions": true,
          "lenient": false,
          "zero_terms_query": "NONE",
          "auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query": true,
          "boost": 1
        }
      }
    },
    "path": "links",
    "ignore_unmapped": false,
    "score_mode": "none",
    "boost": 1
  }
}
```

In code:

```
String fullName = docName + "." + name;
QueryBuilder innerQuery = QueryBuilders.matchQuery(fullName, value);
```